# Integer solutions to a trig equation. Irrational numbers etc.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can the equation 
$$3\left(1\pm 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{n}\right)\right)=\left(1\pm 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi y}{n}\right)\right)\left(1\pm 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi z}{n}\right)\right)$$
Ever have a solution where $(x,y,z)$ are integers other than $\frac{n}{3}$ or $\frac{n}{6}$ ? $n$ is a positive integer. If not, how can I prove this? Thanks!